# Architecture and cabal: how to choose

Tags: haskell, cabal

With `stack` tool I can pass architecture during the build: `stack build ... --arch ARCH`.

How to do the same with `cabal`? Or I just should use relevant GHC compiler for the particular architecture while in the case of `stack` it is itself the orchestrator performing such switch (passing relevant `--with-compiler` option to `cabal`)?

Comment: To me, `--with-compiler` seems reasonable, but I don't feel confident enough to write an authoritative answer. Perhaps others feel similarly. Have you tried `--with-compiler` and found it insufficient for some reason? If yes, say why; if no, then... problem solved I guess.

Comment: @DanielWagner I think this is the way. I will test it very soon, currently I can tell that `--with-compiler` works perfectly with switching from GMP vs. Integer-Simple build, so I think you are right.